# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "21trt5sdsdesd111521" at path "userStories

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi i am installing an application on stackato, I got following error:

2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:        /staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:419
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:                throw err;
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:                      ^
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:        CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "21trt5sdsdesd111521" at path "userStories"
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at ObjectId.cast (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:116:13)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Array.MongooseArray._cast (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:108:30)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Object.map (native)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Array.MongooseArray.push (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:262:23)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Promise.createProjectByDefault (/staging/staged/app/tools/setup-db-demo.js:234:25)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Promise.onResolve (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:162:8)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Promise.emit (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:79:38)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Promise.fulfill (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:92:20)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 staging:            at Query.findOne (/staging/staged/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1784:30)
2014-03-07T03:30:44-0800 stackato.stager: Completed staging application 'jat'

Below is the portion of the code where it makes reference

```
    var story1 = new userStoryModel ({
        id          : '21trt5sdsdesd111521',
        project     : reg.id,
        title       : 'Moving a US from the Current to Done',
        storyType   : 'Feature',
        points      : '5',
        isEstimated : true,
        requester   : player2.id,
        owner       : player1.id,
        description : 'test test test.',
        task        : []
    });
```

Any ideas why is not working ?

Comment: This might be a better for Stackato's support helpdesk.

Comment: Can you post your UserStoryModel code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because your UserStoryModel schema is expecting an ObjectID instead of a string for the id. I'm also confused as to why it is "id" and not "_id" but maybe your particular framework converts it.

Try

```
 var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID; //your particular framework may have an easier way to access this than requireing mongodb
 var story1 = new userStoryModel ({
        id          : new ObjectID('21trt5sdsdesd111521'),
        project     : reg.id,
        title       : 'Moving a US from the Current to Done',
        storyType   : 'Feature',
        points      : '5',
        isEstimated : true,
        requester   : player2.id,
        owner       : player1.id,
        description : 'test test test.',
        task        : []
    });
```